# How am I suppose to estimate the next state vector if the model have internal integration? - Kalman filter

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, kalman-filter, adaptive-control

Assume that we have a state space model with no integration (no poles at 1)

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k)\\y(k) = Cx(k)$$

And we know our kalman gain matrix $K$. To compute the next state $\hat x(k+1)$, we can do this:

$$\hat x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k) + K(y(k) - y_m(k))$$

Where $y_m(k)$ is our real world measurement and $y(k) = Cx(k)$.

But what if we want to have integration in our model.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x(k+1)\\ 
x_i(k+1)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\ 
CA & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
x_i
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
B\\ 
CB
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
u
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
y_i(k+1)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
x_i
\end{bmatrix}$$

How can I estimate the next state vector $\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
x_i
\end{bmatrix}$ if $K$ have the same dimension as $A$?

The reason why I'm asking this is beacuse I have wrote a C-library made for control engineering. I just notice that after I have estimate my model from recursive least square and implement integration into the model, my kalman.c file could not find the next state vector because it's expecting a non-itegration model.

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all if your real measurement $y_m$ comes from the first model, then the second model should reflect this fact, i.e.
$$y(k) = \begin{bmatrix}C & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ x_i\end{bmatrix}$$
In this case the system becomes non-[detectable](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Controllability_and_Observability#Observability). So, the Kalman filter fails to work.

In general, you cannot estimate an integration with only measuring the integrated state in the presence of noise by any method whatsoever. For example, you cannot estimate the position by only measuring the velocity in the presence of noise. This becomes a mathematical impossibility because you lose detectability property.

**Edit:** By "cannot estimate" I mean estimations does not converge to the real values.

Comment: Technically one could still try to estimate it using a Kalman filter, but the estimation error doesn't have to go to zero (even in deterministic case, i.e. no noise and disturbance acting on the system). The error covariance will probably also blow up over time.

Comment: Good! So do you have any suggestions how to estimate the state vectors?

Comment: If it's not possible to have an integration. Then I have to add a reference gain. Right?

Comment: No, you can do nothing unless you get a measurement from the integrated state.

Comment: Well, if you manually calculate the integral then you do kind of "measure" it, with the process noise associated with the integral state equal to the observation noise of the initial system and the observation noise associated with the integral state equal to zero. But probably using this doesn't improve the estimation of the other states.

Comment: @obareey Ok. Well, that answer my question. Do you recommend a static reference gain instead for better tracking?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Do you recommend a static reference gain instead for better tracking?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen If finding an adaptive reference gain (I'm doing adaptive control) then reference gain seems better than computing an integral. Right?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I assume you are referring to something along the lines of [LQI](https://se.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ss.lqi.html)? In that case you can calculate $x_i$ directly by integrating $e$, so no need to include it in the state space model for the Kalman filter.